# Alguien me puede decir o explicar Como Puedo cambiar este windows.Form a Consola para ver de donde vienen esos valores?

Tags: c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, alguien me podria explicar como puedo ver los valores de

```
viewitem.Substring[2].Text = tag.id;
viewitem.Substring[3].Text = tag.readcnt.ToString();
viewitem.Substring[4].Text = tag.rxrssi.ToString();
viewitem.Substring[5].Text = tag.antID.ToString();
viewitem.Substring[6].Text = tag.times.ToString;
```

Quiero ver que valores me arroja en consola por que no puedo visualizarlo bien en el windows.Form

Comment: ¿No puedes usar `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres ver el contenido de variables o expresiones pon [puntos de interrupción](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) o [añade watchers](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019). No cambies todo tu proyecto sólo para ver el contenido de unas variables o expresiones, es importante que aprendas a utilizar las herramientas que el depurador te proporciona para estos casos. Con los enlaces que te he dejado podrás manejarte para estos aspectos.

Comment: @Glown No es necesario modificar tu proyecto introduciendo módulos que te muestren el valor de las variables por consola, si como bien dice Ignasi93 las herramientas con que cuenta el depurador te permiten visualizar el valor de todas las variables, solo tienes que aprender a colocar breakpoint de manera adecuada para visualizar el valor de las variables definidas en el entorno seleccionado. Te recomiendo que esta respuesta dada por Ignasi93 es tu mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

No es la consola pero la simula...

```
Debug.WriteLine("xxxxxxxx").
```

Añade el using

```
'using System.Diagnostics;'
```

Y activa la ventana de salida.

```
Ver -> Salida
```